# Android studio offline mode problems

Tags: android, android-studio

Please just a quick one here, does the newly released android studio 1.0 run well on offline mode? not everyone has free WiFi in his vicinity.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After you have downloaded the SDKs/repositories you need and as far as you do not do any version-control push/pull operations it runs just fine.
Having said that, it's better to stay connected you will likely need online docs and whatever else.

Comment: I wanna download it from the dev site, you would think that everything would come bundled together

Comment: @Light almost everything will be bundled, but you may need to download some updates through the SDK manager.

Comment: Okay I'm basically a newbie and practically learning off tutorials i find online. So i beg you pardon most of my silly questions. When i downloaded the beta version, i was always being prompted to build gradle and other things online, but even when i connected my pc to d internet it still didn't fix the errors i had, so i dumped the Astudio and went back to eclipse. So i don't wanna download this new stable version(823mb) with my mobile data and still have problems using it. Thanks